# "Could not determine the upgrade" while trying to update from 10.10 to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, upgrade

The error message I get on trying to upgrade is

> Could not determine the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:

> E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be
>   caused by held packages.
>
> This can be caused by:  * Upgrading to a pre-release version of
>   Ubuntu  * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu  *
>   Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug against the
>   'update-manager' package and include the files in
>   /var/log/dist-upgrade/ in the bug report.

Following the advice in another forum posting I have already tried `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` but this has not helped. What now? Should I report a bug?

Comment: This problem has now been solved. Uninstalled lots of software using Synaptic, purged PPAs using Ubuntu Tweak and then used the commands sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade. After doing this, upgrade worked with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting answer copied from comment above:

This problem has now been solved. Uninstalled lots of software using Synaptic, purged PPAs using Ubuntu Tweak and then used the commands `sudo apt-get clean, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade`. After doing this, upgrade worked with no problems. – babelproofreader Aug 4 '11 at 9:58