# do-release-upgrade - Could not determine the upgrade

Tags: server, apt, upgrade, updates, do-release-upgrade

**Edit:** Answer at bottom, I'm leaving the question untouch to keep all elements that might match someone else's search.

So, I've read about the issue ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449374/could-not-determine-the-upgrade), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421869/do-release-upgrade-fails-with-could-not-calculate-the-upgrade), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55409/could-not-determine-the-upgrade-while-trying-to-update-from-10-10-to-11-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67698/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-on-distribution-upgrade)) but could not find the help I needed.

It's happening on a server I run for personal usage, so it's not really well maintained. It's running Ubuntu 12.10 (told you!) Server on which I've installed a KDE desktop that I can connect to remotely using  X2Go.

Through SSH, I tried `do-release-upgrade` which resulted in the error in the title.

At this point, I opened the `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` file which ends with

```
Can't guess meta-package 

Your system does not contain a ubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-desktop, 
xubuntu-desktop or edubuntu-desktop package and it was not possible 
to detect which version of Ubuntu you are running. 
Please install one of the packages above first using synaptic or 
apt-get before proceeding.
```

Easy enough... But:

```
$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I also tried

`$ sudo dpkg --configure -a`

followed by

`$ sudo apt-get install -f`

as advised in one of the answers linked above, just in case, but nothing changed/happened.

---

Then I tried to look for `Broken` like advised in one of the cited thread and got this :

```
$ grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
Broken cups-filters:amd64 Conflicts on ghostscript-cups [ amd64 ] < 9.06~dfsg-0ubuntu4 > ( text )
Broken php5-common:amd64 Breaks on php-apc [ amd64 ] < 3.1.13-1 > ( php ) (< 4.0.0)
Broken php5-common:amd64 Breaks on php5-suhosin [ amd64 ] < 0.9.33-3build1 > ( php ) (< 0.9.34)
Broken php5-common:amd64 Breaks on php5-xdebug [ amd64 ] < 2.2.1-1 > ( php ) (< 2.2.2)
Broken python3-pykde4:amd64 Depends on python3 [ amd64 ] < 3.2.3-5ubuntu1.2 -> 3.3.2-14ubuntu1 > ( python ) (< 3.3)
Broken libsnmp30:amd64 Breaks on libsnmp15 [ amd64 ] < 5.4.3~dfsg-2.5ubuntu1.1 > ( libs )
Broken software-properties-kde:amd64 Depends on python3-pykde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python )
Broken python-kde4:amd64 Depends on sip-api-8.1 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libfftw3-double3:amd64 Breaks on libfftw3-3 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.2-3.1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.3.3-1)
Broken apport-kde:amd64 Depends on python3-pykde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python )
Broken ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core [ amd64 ] < 1:0.190.8 -> 1:0.205 > ( admin ) (= 1:0.190.8)
Broken libmuonprivate1:amd64 Depends on software-properties-kde [ amd64 ] < 0.92.9.3 > ( kde )
Broken muon-notifier:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt [ amd64 ] < 1:0.190.8 > ( admin )
Broken gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 Depends on libgtk2.0-0 [ i386 ] < 2.24.13-0ubuntu2 -> 2.24.20-1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (= 2.24.13-0ubuntu2)
Broken muon-updater:amd64 Depends on libmuonprivate1 [ amd64 ] < 1.4.1-0ubuntu1.1 > ( kde ) (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1.1)
Broken userconfig:amd64 Depends on python-kde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python ) (>= 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~)
Broken muon:amd64 Depends on libmuonprivate1 [ amd64 ] < 1.4.1-0ubuntu1.1 > ( kde ) (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1.1)
Broken krita:amd64 Depends on libfftw3-3 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.2-3.1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken muon-installer:amd64 Depends on libmuonprivate1 [ amd64 ] < 1.4.1-0ubuntu1.1 > ( kde ) (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1.1)
Broken usb-creator-kde:amd64 Depends on usb-creator-common [ amd64 ] < 0.2.40ubuntu2 -> 0.2.50 > ( admin ) (= 0.2.40ubuntu2)
Broken apturl-kde:amd64 Depends on python3-pykde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python )
Broken jockey-kde:amd64 Depends on python-kde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python )
Broken plasma-scriptengine-python:amd64 Depends on python-kde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python ) (>= 4:4.6.80)
Broken kde-config-touchpad:amd64 Depends on python-kde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python ) (>= 4:4.5)
Broken kubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on software-properties-kde [ amd64 ] < 0.92.9.3 > ( kde )
Broken php5-ps:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20100525 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken php5-imagick:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20100525 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken php5-mcrypt:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20100525 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken php5-imap:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20100525 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken php5-memcache:amd64 Depends on phpapi-20100525 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 Depends on gtk2-engines-pixbuf [ i386 ] < 2.24.13-0ubuntu2 > ( graphics )
Broken kubuntu-notification-helper:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt [ amd64 ] < 1:0.190.8 > ( admin )
Broken libfftw3-double3:amd64 Breaks on libfftw3-3 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.2-3.1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.3.3-1)
Broken ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core [ amd64 ] < 1:0.190.8 -> 1:0.205 > ( admin ) (= 1:0.190.8)
Broken plasma-widget-facebook:amd64 Depends on plasma-scriptengine-python [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.5-0ubuntu0.1 > ( kde )
Broken krita:amd64 Depends on libfftw3-3 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.2-3.1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken plasma-scriptengine-python:amd64 Depends on python-kde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python ) (>= 4:4.6.80)
Broken ia32-libs:amd64 Depends on ia32-libs-multiarch [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 Depends on gtk2-engines-pixbuf [ i386 ] < 2.24.13-0ubuntu2 > ( graphics )
Broken kubuntu-notification-helper:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt [ amd64 ] < 1:0.190.8 > ( admin )
Broken libfftw3-double3:amd64 Breaks on libfftw3-3 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.2-3.1ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 3.3.3-1)
Broken ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core [ amd64 ] < 1:0.190.8 -> 1:0.205 > ( admin ) (= 1:0.190.8)
Broken plasma-widget-facebook:amd64 Depends on plasma-scriptengine-python [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.5-0ubuntu0.1 > ( kde )
Broken krita:amd64 Depends on libfftw3-3 [ amd64 ] < 3.3.2-3.1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken plasma-scriptengine-python:amd64 Depends on python-kde4 [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.4-0ubuntu0.1 > ( python ) (>= 4:4.6.80)
Broken ia32-libs:amd64 Depends on ia32-libs-multiarch [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 Depends on gtk2-engines-pixbuf [ i386 ] < 2.24.13-0ubuntu2 > ( graphics )
Broken kubuntu-notification-helper:amd64 Depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt [ amd64 ] < 1:0.190.8 > ( admin )
Broken plasma-widget-facebook:amd64 Depends on plasma-scriptengine-python [ amd64 ] < 4:4.9.5-0ubuntu0.1 > ( kde )
Broken ia32-libs:amd64 Depends on ia32-libs-multiarch [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
```

Notice that `kubuntu-desktop` is in the list. Not sure what to do with that...

As a side note, here is the list of PPA or thrid-party repository I've on this server

```
chris-lea-node_js-quantal
dropbox
google-musicmanager
guilhem-fr-vsftpd-quantal
newrelic
nginx-stable-quantal
nilarimogard-webupd8-quantal
tuxpoldo-btsync-quantal
webupd8team-sublime-text-2-quantal
x2go-ppa-quantal
x2go-stable-quantal
```

Which leaves me with a couple of questions:

- Am I supposed to delete all these packages by hand ?
- Will the update go through correctly after that ?
- Should I plan a whole afternoon to fix issues after the upgrade in order to get back a working configuration ? (Like: X2Go, KDE workspace etc...)

---

## Edit:

The actual problem was the unreachable ubuntu mirrors due to the [EOL process](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life).
As pointed in the comment, fixing the source.list helped. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) for ways to fix the source.list.

Thanks to [saiarcot895](https://askubuntu.com/users/241580/) for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: What does `apt-get install -f` say?

Comment: Nothing: `$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Since 12.10 has reached End-Of-Life, did you change the URLs in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: Did you install any packages from extra repositories or PPAs? It would probably be quicker and easier for you to just install a fresh copy of 14.04 at this point. Even if you could fix your upgrade, you would still have to go from 12.10 > 13.04 > 13.10 > 14.04. That is a lot of downloading and potential for failure.

Comment: @saiarcot895 nop, I get 404s when I run `apt-get update` do you have a link I can check for a list of what to change ?

Comment: @JeremieParker: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) question.

Comment: @bain yes I have some PPA's : 
chris-lea-node_js-quantal
dropbox
google-musicmanager
guilhem-fr-vsftpd-quantal
newrelic
nginx-stable-quantal
nilarimogard-webupd8-quantal
tuxpoldo-btsync-quantal
webupd8team-sublime-text-2-quantal
x2go-ppa-quantal
x2go-stable-quantal

Comment: @saiarcot895 you were right, that was the problem. Now I can run the upgrade process.